# Bash does not keep the export variables and aliases in current session. Do you know how to start to investigate this?

Tags: bash, zsh, git-bash

For several day, I have been developing a few scripts and I relied on the fact that when I did "source file.sh" everything that's exported and has aliases into it, will stay to the current session. So, in this way I could developed a set of script to build and deploy my app.

Now, I started to have a problem, after I executed "bash setup.sh" nothing is in my session. I  tried with "bash -i setup.sh" but nothing again.

What could be the issue? I cannot add these in the .bashrc or .zshrc because they are part of a deployment that I am running, and when the session is gone, I want all these variable to be gone as well. I did try this in bash shell and zsh shell, but in both I have the same problem..

Please help with some advise to see what's going wrong.

The only different on the system that's now, is that I updated oh-my-zsh as this asked for an update today. How can I uninstall it, if this caused the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *relied on the fact that when I did "source file.sh" everything that's exported and has aliases into it, will stay to the current session* Where did you get that impression? It's utterly wrong. Besides, you need to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `set -o allexport` before using `source`.